# python metaclass with __new__ for singleton pattern not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a singleton pattern using metaclass. When i use `__new__` method in metaclass it is not getting called when creating the object in it child class and returning the newly created object but when i use `__call__` method in metaclass it works fine. I am using python 3.
Here is my code:

```
class meta_class(type):
    _instance = {}
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if cls not in cls._instance:
        inst = cls._instance[cls] = super(meta_class,cls).__new__(cls,*args,**kwargs)
        return inst
    else:
        return cls._instance[cls]

class example(metaclass=meta_class):
    def __init__(self):
        print("instance init")

o = example()
print(o)
p = example()
print(p)
```

Any help would be more appreciable.

Comment: o and p objects have different address in memory when i use __new__ in metaclass.

Comment: The indentation is incorrect and I'm not sure why you want to use `__new__` if you know that `__call__` works.

Comment: sorry,for the indentation it got distorted when i post and what i want to know here what's the difference when i use __call__ why it is working ?

Comment: Then update the question to fix the indentation and state your question **clearly**.

Comment: i updated it already thanks.

Comment: But it's still not correctly indented.

Comment: sorry, it is ok now

Comment: may i know why its not working with __new__ ??